# "Character 2 experience" for data entry?

Tags: career-development, work-experience

I'm applying for a few data entry/administrative support roles, and the advertisements request "Character 2 experience". Usually this is followed by a request for 10 key experience.

I don't know what this is. I've tried Googling it, but all I find is stuff related to video games.

Is it software? Is it technique? What is "character 2"?

Edit: As requested, the specifics of one of the advertisements...

> Data Entry Clerk
>
> Description:
>
> - Seeking an Administrative Assistant to schedule appointments, give information to callers, and take dictation.
> - Composes memos, transcribes notes, and researches and creates presentations.
> - Generates reports, handles multiple projects, and prepares and monitors invoices and expense reports.
> - Assist with compiling and developing the annual budget.
>
> Requirements:
>
> - **Character 2 experience**
> - 10 Key helpful, but not required
> - Some college or higher, preferred
> - 5+ years Data Entry/Clerical experience

Comment: A country would be useful as well, it may be locale-specific.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this field but "10 keys" for a data entry position makes me think about the numerical keypad (or a standalone task specific version of it)

Comment: Link about 10 Key: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/data-entry-10key-14045.html Basically its a method of entering numerical data using the number keys (0-9) on the right side of the keyboard.

Comment: Just a guess, but it could be some specific software product related to the position.

Comment: What is "character 2"? is a clear question to me.   Odd question but OP is just going by what was on a job posting.

Comment: Call the one you'd least like to work in, treat them as a 'burner', and ask them what it is.

Comment: [Going on some job searches that I've found, it looks to be an American thing](https://www2.jobdiva.com/candidates/myjobs/openjob_outside.jsp?a=2gjdnwpwd3uyd10hul4jfsqc7h8ghe01efylnsiet9ijm73f2wbgiuxyadpfh76m&id=10567302)

Comment: Yes, I'm an American, if it helps.

Comment: One other thing I've found in my searches, is that I also find a lot of stuff regarding ASCII characters. I don't know if it's relevant.

Comment: Is it possibly a job in a medical office? "Character 2" has relevance with respect to ICD-10 encoding.

Comment: At the risk of sounding simplistic, surely the people to ask are the company advertising ?  Even if asking ruled you out of one job (not necessarily), at least you'd know what was meant when looking for others.  It sounds like specific software to me, but I've not heard of it myself.

Comment: I wager that the '10 key' thing refers to the classical '10 finger typing' method?

Comment: "Character 2 experience" without additional context here is clearly a vague and poorly worded requirement. I suspect it's internally used in their performance reviews. I'd ignore it in your application. Here is a great resource on clear writing:
http://www.archives.gov/federal-register/write/legal-docs/clear-writing.html Good luck with your hunt!

Comment: @Cronax '10 key' is a way of typing involving the numberical keyboard. My mom learned it in her 80s data entry job. It is a very quick way to enter numberical data if you know how, but, obviously, only suitable for numberical data

Comment: @IAmBob did you read this in one or several advertisements? Perhaps knowing the specific industry/company/context that placed those adds could shed a light on the meaning

Comment: What is the location of the job?

Answer (score 1):

I remembered seeing an article about inter-key times for typists, it talked about character 1, character 2 and mid-key positions in relation to the delay between starting and completing the given or denoted word. I never really fully understood it if I'm being honest.

After a bit of googling I found a google snippet from the book which can be found [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YSHnBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA232&ots=RHbo3BpFoX&dq=typists%20Character%202&pg=PA232#v=onepage&q=typists%20Character%202&f=false).

At it's core I think it's a discussion of techniques to help with cognitive delay when typing or copying, but if someone else has a better explanation then please jump in. It's a little outside of my comfort zone.

---

> Interkey times were likewise assessed with respect to word length. The
>   obtained patterns, averaged over typists, with initial latencies
>   excluded are summarized in Figure 9.3 (the times shown at any
>   character position represent the average interkey time between
>   character n - 1 and character n). The initial latency was followed by
>   a relatively short interval from character 1 to character 2...

(snippet from page 231)